# Limit time user is allowed on website before forcing a login

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm not sure what language to use (php, Java or other) but I'll need to limit the amount of time a user is allowed to browse our website before forcing a login popup appears.

Example:

Unregistered user browsing our website, after 1mins of browsing we show a popup saying they need to log on to continue browsing.

If anyone has a better way of doing this I'd be happy to adapt.

Apologies for being extremely vague.

Comment: You'll want to do this client-side in JavaScript.  Also know that there are plenty of ways around this.

Comment: @Brad Although if the user keeps changing pages, won't the counter keep being reset?

Comment: Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: Whether he wants to do this client or server side depends - I guess he just wants to prevent going to a NEW page when the timeout hits. Only if he also wants to limit the time spent on the page the user is currently on does he need to do this in the client, for example, when someone reads a 100 pages long document that is one long webpage and it would give him an hour of free reading time :)
Anyway - given the vague question all we can say is "Yes" ;-)

Comment: Use JavaScript. And if you don't want too much restriction . You can create a cookie and can update its value through JavaScript till the time u want user to be on site. After it is zero , you can popup login .  But if u want to restrict user Soo much that there is no alternative to skip popup. Then use anything server side.

Comment: @PankhuriKaushik This is why I like "NY Times" Website, or was it "The Economist"? I have an easy workaround for both of them, all I remember is "turn JS off" for one and "use anonymous browsing window for new articles" for the other.

Comment: Yaa that's what . But when people try to hack your site that means people are actually interested in site. When a person is too restricted then user doesn't even try to spend time to login also.. anyways depends on your requirement.  You ll have to use server-side language. Use any language you like, in every server side language it can implemented.

Comment: I would setup a column in DB such as `registered` (for example) with options of `YES` or `NO` if user is not registered, then column is set to `NO` and show content accordingly, while using sessions and even a token. **Forget using `JS`**, it's a waste of coding time for one thing.

Comment: @General_Twyckenham No, you can simply set a cookie or local storage and track the time there.

Answer (score 2):

as JustinM151 or Mörre and others allready pointed out you may be informed that all implementations are "not safe" for bypassing this task.

you can use `sessions` for this like

```
session_start();

$expire_seconds = 60; // expire in 60 seconds

if( ! isset( $_SESSION['visit_expire'] ) {
    $_SESSION['visit_expire'] = time() + $expire_seconds;
}

if( !$isLoggedIn && $_SESSION['visit_expire'] > time() ) {
    // force login
    // display whatever 
}
```

Comment: you beat me to the punch, but this is bypassed pretty easily too.

Comment: How so? Sessions are server-side, not client-side. @JustinM151

Comment: Justin M151 please give an explanation for your opinion

Comment: @ins0 Open each new page in a new "anonymous browsing" window. This is how I get free articles at The Economist :) The new anon. window doesn't have your session cookie... it doesn't keep cookies so for the website you are always a new visitor with each new anon. window.

Comment: You may have a point there, but that would render useless if a user is not logged in via DB, in association with using sessions. A few gauntlets to break through first. @Mörre

Comment: ah now i get your point... when u delete your session key (client side) the timer is reset. i think u can do a lot of implementations but all are "unsecure"

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, with login-requirement it works, but look at the question we are handling here, at the top... they are not logged in, that's the whole point :)

Comment: Well, a login-requirement to read anything works. As soon as you do it like NYTimes or The Economist, where any article is available for free without login, they merely attempt to limit how many you can read, you are screwed :) But those sites would loose all the casual readers - potential subscribers - if they forced everyone to have a login.

Comment: True. Then the OP will need to set it up directly into DB, instead of having information readily available to anyone, registered or not. That's the way I would do it by setting up a column especially for it. JS is next to useless in this case. @Mörre

Comment: reset your ip and you can go on... i would do this by useing session, db and this method http://lucb1e.com/rp/cookielesscookies/

Comment: There's (potentially) a slight problem with using this technique. What if a user disables image viewing? @ins0

Comment: just as I was gonna give my explanation, its already been explained :)

Comment: as i allready said and edited my post...all implementations are "not safe" and don't guarantee 100% when you deal with anonymous users

Comment: If I was really concerned about people bypassing JS or Session vars I would just store IP's in a DB, if someone wants to view the site for 1 minute, then switch to a proxy for the next minute... well, they are dedicated and have earned their free content LOL!

Comment: Then there surely must be a way to kick out anonymous (browsing) users. Someone came up with that idea, so that someone (or someone else) must have come up with a way to prevent anonymous browsing. @ins0

Comment: @Fred-ii- the best option would be to only expose part of the content and require log in to see the rest. You aren't going to get a 100% way to lock down an anonymous user.

Comment: You've got something there @JustinM151 as for "not going to get 100%" there is and right at the gate. `$gate=".htaccess";` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You will want to do this in Javascript to have it stop themin their tracks, however, if you want to restrict further browsing after the time limit, you can use PHP/SESSION variables to stop them from moving on to new pages.

When they first access your site set a session variable with the time.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['browseTime'] = date('U'); //Seconds since Unix Epoch
```

then on every page load check their browse time compared to current time...

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['browseTime'])) {
    if(date('U') - $_SESSION['browseTime'] > $secondsAllowed) {
        header('location: login.php?timesup=y');
    }
}
```

granted they can easily bypass this method or the javascript method by clearing their cookies.

A way to do this that is harder to bypass is to store their times in a database table tied to their IP address. but that too can be bypassed.